# Mathematica's definition of cos(kA) where A is the 1st Pauli spin matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, trigonometry

For a homework assignment I was asked to derive the formula of $e^{ik\sigma_{1}}$ - where $\sigma_{1}$ is the Pauli spin matrix `{{0,1},{1,0}}` - using the Taylor series definitions of sin, cos and Euler's identity. The answer I got was $\sin(kA)=\sin(k)A$ and $\cos(kA)=\cos(k)I$. To check my work I plugged in the following code to Mathematica: `A = PauliMatrix[1]; Cos[k*A]` and this was the output: `{{1,cos(k)}, {cos(k),1}}` which doesn't agree with my definition of cos(kA) (which is also confirmed by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions_of_matrices). Is the Mathematica definition of cos(kA) wrong or did I define something incorrectly?

Comment: Use [`MatrixExp`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixExp.html).  `Cos` has the Attribute [Listable](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html), so it's being evaluated on the matrix elements (i.e. {{Cos@0,Cos@k},{Cos@k,Cos@0}})

Comment: As @Adam pointed out, `MatrixExp[I k A]` or `MatrixFunction[Cos, k*A] + I*MatrixFunction[Sin, k*A]`